# How to send arguments with slurpfile and jq?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to convert this query:

```
cat input_file.json | jq '.arrlstProperty[] | select(.code == "123" or .code=="345" or .code="678")' > output.json
```

Into this:

```
cat input_file.json | jq '.arrlstProperty[] | select($codes[0])' --slurpfile codes args.json > sal.json

-- args.json: 
[".code==\"123\" or .code==\"234\""]
```

But it's not working, the select filter is not being applied. I know because just returns all the elements in the arrlstProperty array.

The reason of why I'm doing in that way is because I need to send too many codes (more than 50K) in the select.

This is the error if try to send more than 2K codes:

```
jq: error: function compiled to 77856 bytes which is too long
```

Simplified structure of my json file:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 100,
    "action": "UPDATE",
    "years_experience": 0
  },
  "arrlstProperty": [
    {
      "id": 12345,
      "code": "EB-123",
      "galleries": [
        {
          "action": "UPDATE",
          "id": 90,
          "alt": "Foto de nave industrial en renta en  , antigua santa rosa, apodaca, nuevo león, 11448639 No. 01"
        },
        {
          "action": "UPDATE",
          "id": 91,
          "alt": "Foto de nave industrial en renta en  , antigua santa rosa, apodaca, nuevo león, 11448639 No. 02"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 12346,
      "code": "EB-234",
      "galleries": [
        {
          "action": "UPDATE",
          "id": 92,
          "alt": "Foto de nave industrial en renta en  , antigua santa rosa, apodaca, nuevo león, 11448639 No. 01"
        },
        {
          "action": "UPDATE",
          "id": 93,
          "alt": "Foto de nave industrial en renta en  , antigua santa rosa, apodaca, nuevo león, 11448639 No. 02"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: No, it's a unique property in every element of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slurping is unnecessary here.

Populate `args.json` with `code` values to be selected, it'll look like this:

```
"123"
"234"
```

Then convert `arrlstProperty` into an object by keying each element with its `code` value, then index resulting object with keys stored in `args.json`. E.g:

```
jq '.arrlstProperty | INDEX(.code)[inputs]' input_file.json args.json
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/i5SGdecOT8)</sup>

Comment: I'm getting this error: `jq: error: INDEX/1 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
. | .arrlstProperty | INDEX(.code)[inputs]
jq: 1 compile error` I suppose it's because of the json structure, I've tried to adapt your query without success. Am I missing something?

Comment: oh! It's good to notice!
Can INDEX() work with strings? I've installed the jq 1.6 and now I'm getting this error: `jq: error (at : input_file.json 2): Cannot index number with string "code"`

Comment: Oh thx! I've modified the question in order to have visibility of the input

Comment: You are right, it's working with the input and the jq play. I don't know why it's not working on the console. I need to check the input_json structure I guess. Thx for your response.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a script for version < 1.6

```
jq '.arrlstProperty | map(.code as $x | select( any($codes[]; . == $x )))' --slurpfile codes args.json input_file.json
```